# Calling a Service from within a Restangular ResponseInterceptor (ResponseExtractor)

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm trying to expand a Foreign Key field on an element I get from my back end service after adding an item to a collection, using Restangular.

The service responds to my POST with the element, including a `url` field linking to the related object, and I already have a service in place for those objects.

The response looks like:

```
{
    "url": "http://api.example.com/resources/6/", 
    "name": "Harry", 
    "role": "http://api.example.com/roles/1/", 
}
```

and I'd like to expand the `role` field to something like:

```
{
    "url": "http://api.example.com/resources/6/", 
    "name": "Harry", 
    "role": "Administrator", 
}
```

so far I have the following:

```
Configurer.setResponseInterceptor(function(data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
    if ((operation == 'post' || operation == 'put') && what == 'resources' && 'role' in data && data.role.substr(0,4) == 'http') {
        console.log('Role URL instead of name -- change this');
    }
    return data;
});
```

and I'd ideally like to call my existing service which wraps Restangular; do I need an injector? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Alternatively, and more usefully, I'd like the `role` field expanded into the full Role object so I can use permissions etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, the goal from the original question *is* possible.

"Calling a Service from within a Restangular ResponseInterceptor"

example:

```js
angular.module('app').factory('myApi', [
  'Restangular', 'myService', '$rootScope', function(restangular, myService, $rootScope) {
    return restangular.withConfig(function(c) {
      c.setResponseInterceptor(function(data, op, what, url, response, deferred) {
        if (op === 'post' && what === 'the_name_of_some_resource' && url.match(/something_or_other/)) {
          myService.doSomething(response.data.something_cool);
          $rootScope.$emit('didSomethingCool');
        }
        return response.data;
      });
    });
  }
]);
```

Then just inject myApi and use it in place of Restangular. The response interceptor has access to myService. Note, this is not great design (hard to test), but something along these lines came in handy for me, to put off the need to refactor a bunch of spread-out code that was directly calling a restangular method, so I thought I'd share it here. Instead of refactoring all the direct restangular calls into a service (better design), this was a way to tie into the requests/responses of some API activity that is called in multiple places and suddenly needed some state to be modified whenever the response was received.

The $rootScope part is not essential to the OP's question, I included it to illustrate that you can inject arbitrary stuff (not providers) into a factory which supplies restangular with a modified config; this of course includes your own service instances, which can then be called from the response interceptor.

Another note: setResponseInterceptor is deprecated, and it's successor addResponseInterceptor has a different signature (I think)

None of this was tested and I haven't checked my facts.

Answer (score 1):

Check this post:

http://ath3nd.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/15/

There is an example of just that: augmenting a return by the server.

Since Restangular returns a promise, to preserve that flow, you would have to return a promise as well in your service, for which you would have to inject the $q service.

Comment: Ah OK. At the moment I have a bit of a hybrid approach that the article implies I should change; I have additional methods added to my Restangular collection via the addElementTransformer method, and these are responsible for the POST, basically sidestepping the service I created; hence my use of the ResponseInterceptor.

Do you know if there's a Restangular way to access another restangular object from within the interceptor? Or do I need to refactor?

Comment: As the author of the article, I would suggest you refactor, even if there is a way to do what you want to do. Simple goes a long way with me.

Comment: So I've bitten the bullet and started the refactoring according to your blog post - it's already looking much better and there are ways of doing everything I'm after: thank you. However, I've come across a very strange issue now, would you know anything about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798586/angularjs-multiple-promises-resolving-erratically