# AngularJS: multiple promises resolving erratically

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am assigning two collections into my scope in a controller; both come from services wrapping RestAngular and return promises. Each individually returns the collection I want, but when I assign both to $scope one of them never resolves (it's the same one that fails, no matter the order they're in).

If I log to console by calling the offending service again, then lo and behold the original assignment works perfectly.

The services both work pretty much the same:

```
.factory('Role', ['Restangular', '$q', function(Restangular, $q){
        var _collection = [];
        var _roleService = Restangular.all('roles');

        return {
            getList: function() {
                // return _roleService.getList();
                var listDeferred = $q.defer();
                _roleService.getList()
                .then(function(list) {
                    listDeferred.resolve(list);
                    _collection = list;
                });
                return listDeferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
])
```

and the controller is specified as follows (I've left the console.log in, but removing it causes $scope.roles to never resolve):

```
.controller('ResourceCtrl', ['$scope', 'Resource', 'Role', function($scope, Resource, Role) {
    $scope.roles = Role.getList();
    $scope.resources = Resource.getList();

    console.log(Role.getList());
}])
```

Everything is done within Angular so I don't think I'm missing an $apply - but unless I've stumbled on a bug there must be something wrong with my code...

**EDIT**

I found out what's causing the error, but don't have a solution. My Resource service is very similar to the Role one, but because Resources have Roles, I inject Role into Resource and use it to link individual elements together. Once I deleted that line all the scope / promise stuff came back.

Which I guess takes me back to: how do I link services together reliably (i.e. so Resources with role fields can have the corresponding Role objects attached to them at the service level).

Here's my Resource:

```
.factory('Resource', ['Restangular', '$q', 'Role',
    function(Restangular, $q, Role){
        var _resourceService = RestAngular.all('resources');
        var _roleService = Role;

        var _convertObjectsToUrls = function(item) {
            for (var property in item) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof(item[property]) == 'object' && item[property] != null) {
                    item[property] = item[property].url;
                }
            }
            return item;
        }

        var _convertUrlsToObjects = function(item) {
            for (var property in item) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(property) && typeof(item[property]) == 'string' && item[property] != '' && property != 'url' && item[property].substr(0,4) == 'http') {
 /* THIS LINE BREAKS IT */                       item[property] = _roleService.getByUrl(item[property]);
                }
            }
            return item;
        }

        var _getIdFromUrl = function(url) {
            var pathElements = url.split('/')
            return pathElements[pathElements.length - 2]
        }

        var _cleanParams = function(item) {
            for (var property in item) {
                if (item.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    item[property] = undefined;
                }
            }
            return item;
        }

        return {
            add: function(item) {
                var responseDeferred = $q.defer();
                item = _convertObjectsToUrls(item);

                _resourceService.post(item)
                .then(function(response){
                    response = _convertUrlsToObjects(response);
                    response.name = response.first_name + ' ' + response.last_name;

                    _collection.push(response);
                    responseDeferred.resolve(response);

                    item = _cleanParams(item);
                });
                return responseDeferred.promise;
            },
            edit: function(item) {
                var responseDeferred = $q.defer();
                var idx = _collection.indexOf(item);
                item = _convertObjectsToUrls(item);

                item.customPUT(_getIdFromUrl(item.url))
                .then(function(response){
                    response = _convertUrlsToObjects(response);
                    response.name = response.first_name + ' ' + response.last_name;

                    _collection.splice(idx, 1, response)
                    responseDeferred.resolve(response);
                });
                return responseDeferred.promise;
            },
            delete: function(item) {
                var responseDeferred = $q.defer();
                var idx = _collection.indexOf(item);
                // item = _convertObjectsToUrls(item);

                item.customDELETE(_getIdFromUrl(item.url), {})
                .then(function(response){
                    response = _convertUrlsToObjects(response);

                    _collection.splice(idx, 1)
                    responseDeferred.resolve(response);
                });
                return responseDeferred.promise;
            },
            getList: function() {
                var listDeferred = $q.defer();
                var list = _resourceService.getList()
                .then(function(list) {
                    _.each(list, function(item, index, list){
                        item = _convertUrlsToObjects(item);
                        item.name = item.first_name + ' ' + item.last_name;
                    })
                    listDeferred.resolve(list);
                    _collection = list;
                });
                return listDeferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from where the Resource service comes and whether is is of importance. Since you return a promise in your Role service, you can just do:

```
.controller('ResourceCtrl', ['$scope', 'Role', function($scope, Role) {
    Role.getList().then(function(roles){
         $scope.roles = roles;
    });
}])
```

Alternatively, you can let Angular resolve the role for you (if you are just using the roles in a template, for example)

```
.controller('ResourceCtrl', ['$scope', 'Role', function($scope, Role) {
      $scope.roles = Role.getList();
 }])
```

Edit: I also noticed the  `var _collection = [];` which seems not needed. Maybe you can also post the code for the Resource service?
This code of your Role service should be sufficient.

```
.factory('Role', ['Restangular', '$q', function(Restangular, $q){
        return {
            getList: function() {
                var listDeferred = $q.defer();
                Restangular.all('roles').getList().then(function(list) {
                    listDeferred.resolve(list);
                });
                return listDeferred.promise;
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Even further edit:

This plunkr shows that in angular 1.2rc3 the first method works:
http://embed.plnkr.co/SU5UMK7jNffXWnWiV1HE/preview

But if you were to try to take advantage of the automatic unrwapping of promises (which is deprecated in rc3, you are out of luck):
http://embed.plnkr.co/zdepkLCesYkj8pXYFTN2/preview

Comment: How is your second suggestion different from what OP is doing ?

Comment: It is not much different indeed, only subtly. You would notice that the Resource service is not injected. This is because, I believe, if the Resource service is done in the same way as the Role service, injection order overrides the underscore service definitions (e.g _roleService).

Comment: I don't know much about AngularJS, but I would find it strange if the injection order of the controller's constructor had anything to do with the injection order of the factory contructor.

Comment: I omitted the Resource service because it's basically the same as the Role one at this point apart from Restangular configuration. I've tried the other ways of assigning the collections to the scope (e.g. in `then`) to no avail. Removing the `_roleService` var also doesn't seem to help. Does anyone understand why the `console.log` call (or any further call) causes it to work?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in angular. What version are you using?

Comment: 1.2.0rc1. I just tried creating the issue in Plunkr but couldn't replicate it. Here's what it looks like (taken from the Restangular template) http://plnkr.co/edit/KKtSwi?p=preview

Comment: It is worth to note that Angular will soon deprecate auto resolving of promises.

Comment: I didn't know that - thanks for the update. I tried going down to 1.1.5 before I found the problem (although not the reason); question updated above...

Comment: yo, I would revise my backend a bit. It seems you are piecing together Resources and Roles in client side, while it would be better if you could get them already pieced together by the backend. It would save you http requests (cause now you are making a request for each Resource and then for its Roles, while it can be the same). But if revising backend code is not an option, there is no problem with the current approach you are having, only you need to remember that your services are returning promises, so you would have to use their 'then' methods when resolving stuff.